# Where are my installed applications?

Tags: package-management

I have installed Skype in Ubuntu, but I do not know where to start the installed the Skype application .Similarly  I have installed Netbeans and other applications but their icons are not appearing in any menus.

Related: how to uninstall already installed applications?

Comment: So how do I find the answers?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The executables are located in the `/usr/bin` folder. I guess pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing

```
skype
```

will do. It might also fall under the Applications menu > Internet.

To uninstall already installed software, you can:

1. Go to Software-center. Find the software and remove.
2. Open a terminal, and type

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove <software-name>
   ```

If you do not know the complete name, just type a few characters of the application, and press tab twice. That will auto complete, or show a list of matching applications.

Comment: You don't need the whole path when using Alt+F2 (or the terminal or desktop/panel shortcuts). Just typing `skype` will suffice.

Comment: Oops, overlooked that! Thanks for the heads-up. But there was a time that I had to give the entire path. Dont remember the applicaton now.

Comment: You have to give the full path if you don't install it "properly"...

Comment: you can find local software in /usr/local also.

Comment: Where is installed application's folder?! For example tomcat7 folder.

Answer (score 31):

You can discover where a package puts its 'stuff' by running:

```
dpkg -L 'packagename'
```

There's still a set of 'standard' locations that programs are put into. For example, binaries (in windows parlance 'executables') are put in /usr/bin, and documentation is put in /usr/share/doc in a Ubuntu system.

This is a pretty simplistic answer. For more details about how linux/unix directories are typically structured, see this:

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

Answer (score 10):

There are some very good answers to a similar question to yours over at

[What is the Linux equivalent to Windows' Program Files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/27213/70874)

But the general idea is that the /bin and /usr/bin are where the start up application files (executables or scripts) are stored. The direct equivalent of "Program Files" though is probably /usr/share this is the directory that contains the various support files for most applications

For a good overview of the Ubuntu file structure check out the link below.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview

Comment: Many of the files in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are scripts, but more are actual binary executables.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Program Files" Directory in Linux. The Application's Parts are distributed according to what they are. There are a lot of explanations of the Directory Structure out there, you can use [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/linux-or-ubuntu-directory-structure.html) one for a start.