# Partitioning for dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed along windows 8 but i want to reinstall it because of system problems and wrong partitioning. My computer has 2 separate discs.I am using ubuntu on only one of them and would like to use both. Computer has 119GB SSD (C:) and 2TB HDD (D:). Windows and ubuntu are both installed on the SSD. I use HDD for storing games and personal files (i have lots of them!). Ubuntu partition takes about 36GB of SSD and windows the rest. Ubuntu set-up: /home 10GB, root 25GB and swap 1GB but /home partition is too small. How should i do the partitioning so that ubuntu uses SSD and HDD?

set-up once again: 119GB SSD 
ubuntu: 36GB of which 1GB swap, 25GB /home, 10GB /root
windows: 83GB

2TB HDD: windows only, but i want ubuntu there as well.

How do i make it happen?

Comment: This is a confusing question. Do you want Ubuntu on the SSD or the 2TB HDD or both? Also, you don't NEED a /home partition, easy way is to use just a large (30GB +) / partition, it will include /home and it can use as much of the space as it needs in the partition. Also your swap should be the same size as your ram.

Comment: preferably both, but only hdd is also option. I have 16GB of ram so i thought that i dont need swap so much.  So do i set my / to take large amount and little or not at all /home?

Comment: Just make sure the partition is big enough, you can have a separate /home and / but they must both be big enough or you can just have one partition as / (/home is a sub folder of /). For why more swap, it is really up to you but it is good practice to have enough (you don't need double for desktop). Make your 2TB look some thing like this >>> swap: 4-8GB Ubuntu: 100GB or more Windows:100GB or more and format any free space as NTFS for sheared file storage, this way the OS's have plenty of space to work and you can keep other stuff in the space.

Comment: Use 36GB SSD as `/` partition, on HDD double of your RAM as `swap` partition and as much as you like as `/home` partition. Also you can use [symbolic link](http://askubuntu.com/q/56339/255257) to map your Home's folders to another partition in HDD. See [How to combine an SSD boot drive with a HDD data drive?](http://askubuntu.com/a/62161/255257)

Comment: @MarkKirby I did exactly like you told to (thanks!) but is it possible ?to install ubuntu-applications to that 1,8TB partition or do they definitely go to / ? I guess windows-things will easily be installed in there, how about ubuntu?

Comment: Not really, Ubuntu needs ext4, the reason for NTFS is Windows wil not even see and EXT4 partition, it is best of a bad situation. Are you using some large programs? Perhaps Steam? 100GB is loads of space for Ubuntu’s system and most of the software centre.

Comment: Here is a good read on the subject http://askubuntu.com/questions/313592/how-to-install-applications-to-a-separate-hdd

Comment: well yes i am using steam and games in general but it will be easier to play on windows (Thats why i left it there) and thus i may not even use all that space. Mostly just curiosity

Comment: OK, I do use a sheared steam partition, for Ubuntu and windows, you can install the games to the NTFS on any OS. Open Steam >> Properties >> Downloads >> here you can set a diffrent directory for your games, they will work on both but require a small update each time you switch the OS you are playing on. Ubuntu can play the games fine from NTFS. It is just the app data (stem.bin etc) that needs to be in /.

Comment: Mark Kirby, do you need a swap partition on both drives?