# How do I change the Default Drive for installing apps

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

1. Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
2. Chose the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".
3. I have 2 disks. (1) SSD, 120GB, (1) HDD, 1TB

Coming from windows, how do automatically mount my 2nd drive (HDD)?
And how do I set all the folders Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Videos, and all other apps to install to the HDD? Where the SSD would only act as a drive for the OS.

Or is this possible?

Comment: Not as easy as in Windows, needs planning in advance. [How to install applications to a separate hdd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313592/how-to-install-applications-to-a-separate-hdd)

Comment: Can use the 'something else' option(at bottom) and use SSD for /(root) and HDD for /home(data).  Root can be a small partition ~30GBs or bigger.  Will also need a EFI partition of about ~300MBs.  Home can be whole HDD if you expect to download a lot.

Comment: If you installed everything on your ssd and your hdd is currently empty, you should move the `/home` directory to hdd by following this procedure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving