# Question about disks management

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 21.04, disk-management

So, can you apply the same logic than in Windows when you install the S.O in the fastest disk (NvMe) Important programs and games in second fastest drive (SSD) and movies and heavyweight files in HDD? Because I feel that everything got installed in only one disk, is there a way to manage this like in windows? (ie. When you make `sudo apt-get install <something>` it's always installed in the main disk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [How to install applications to a separate hdd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313592/how-to-install-applications-to-a-separate-hdd).

Even though it is possible, Windows works fundamentally different than Linux.  It is a good idea to learn the *NIX directory structure and work within it.  If you are not familiar with Unix/Linux/Ubuntu, I would recommend that you leave things where they are.

Instead, make room for your operating systems and most frequently used software on your fastest drive.  As you pointed out, it's better for software (including your OS) to be located on a fast drive.

Most linux software takes up a very small amount of space.  Notable exceptions would be video games, but the platforms for very large games (ex. Steam) allow you to choose the destination for software without negatively affecting the UNIX directory structure.

The primary technical reason why your software runs better on solid state storage compared to a mechanical drive is because software routinely needs simultaneous access to lots of different files which are often stored in many different sectors located in different parts of the drive.  A mechanical disk has to physically seek to access sectors whereas a solid state drive does not have this limitation.  This makes the "random read speed" insanely faster on SSDs than mechanical hard drives.

Meanwhile, something like a several GB video file is more likely to be stored sequentially on the drive.  SSDs are still typically faster at reading these files, but a mechanical disk is not necessarily slowed down by having to seek.  You also typically load documents, pictures, movies, etc, "on demand" one at a time, rather than having to load a bunch of them all at the same time.  You can always keep these files on any mounted file system that Ubuntu can read and write, so they will not need to take up space on your root file system if you do not want them there.

Comment: But what about If I ran out of space? Lets say I have a 512Gb NvMe as main, 1Tb ssd as secondary and 4Tb HDD for big files, once reached the 512 Gb capacity how linux know where to install the rest of programs? Because I prefer to use the SSD than the HDD

Comment: Are you going to dual boot?  You won't get even close to 512 GB with just Ubuntu and its software

Comment: Yeah actually that 512 gb drive is used by windows and linux is in the 1 tb bc I suspect that you cant easily select  where to install programs, Im concerned about that games that dont run natively and I will need to use the hdd to save it there using wine or playonlinux or lutris etc. Just imagine how heavyweight is cod like 150 gb.

Comment: I believe that lutris is similar to steam where you can install games wherever you'd like.  What is not recommended is that to attempt to relocate software that is installed from sources, like software from `apt` or the GUI package manager.  This software will end up on the same partition as the root file system but Ubuntu + a full suite of apt software won't get close to filling up 512 GB, definitely not 1TB.  As long as you aren't storing large files on your root file system, 100 GB would be plenty