# Find the location of an installed application to type in the Launch Application window

Tags: dialog

Many times I get this dialog when opening some files. It asks me to choose a program. I don't know where all programs reside and what to select? Where to find installed applications in Ubuntu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the appropriate program to open that file. Most of the programs on Ubuntu are installed in `/usr/bin/` directory. So, once you click **"Choose"** and the window pops up for you to  navigate to the program, navigate through `/usr/bin/` and find the appropriate program. For example, if you have clicked on a torrent/magnet link, you would select `transmission-gtk`. To open an application installed in a custom directory, you need to navigate through that directory and select the program.

If you can't find the application in `/usr/bin/`; then the other appropriate directories to look out for are `/bin/`, `/usr/share/`, `/usr/local/`, `/opt/`. See the following question for further details:

- [What is the Linux equivalent to Windows' Program Files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27213/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-windows-program-files-folder-where-do-things-g)

Comment: I think you are better off using the terminal `which app_name` it is faster then navigating through all the various system directories in the GUI. YMMV.