# How to install software to a different hard drive?

Tags: software-center, hard-drive, software-installation, configuration, disk

Hello my main hard drive that I have Ubuntu installed on is almost completely used now so I need to figure out how to properly install software on a second hard drive(non-usb). I have already reformatted the hard drive to ext4 using gparted and I have mounted the hard drive to a folder I created the path for, the path is /hdd if needed Also, will simply dragging files for software to my other hard drive work?

Comment: Also take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/27213/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-windows-program-files-folder-where-do-things-g

Comment: Solved I dragged all things for the program to my mount point and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not expand your current partition? I would advise (if that is not possible) that you don't install the programs, but you have your Home space (i.e. Documents, Downloads etc) on there - that is probably much easier than trying to install over there.