# Check Software Version

Tags: command-line, vlc

I need to check the current version of VLC I have running, however I don't know where it is installed (can't see it in `/etc` or `/bin`).

If I do `vlc` in a terminal then the application starts, but is there a way to do like a `pwd vlc` command where it shows me the actual path of where the `vlc` app is being called from?

I want to see if the actual file name contains the software version since I can't find the version within the software itself.

I have a statement asking me to explain why this is different from another post. It is different because this is a 2 part question, where I am trying to understand the install package location (which is the same as the other link), however I also wanted to know how to check the VLC version, hence the title (and why this question is different).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find and run an application that's already installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/501308/how-can-i-find-and-run-an-application-thats-already-installed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command :

```
vlc --version
```

Most of the programs (i have used) provide their version by the `--version` option.

Also you should check the `man` page of the commands to get details idea about them.

**EDIT :**

There are many ways to check where a binary file is stored, `vlc` in this case :

```
type -a vlc
command -v vlc
which vlc
```

Comment: lol. I love how simple the answer is. Thank you. Can I ask if you know if there is an actual way to check the directory of a program? I will tick this as the answer in 11 mins when it allows me to do it.

Comment: @johnsmith check my edits..

Comment: I like that which command, that seems to be finding them all. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Also other commands that can be found within different SE websites:

```
apt-show-versions vlc
```

But it has to be installed `sudo apt-get install apt-show-versions` then it will output for example:

```
vlc:i386/trusty 2.2.1~trusty uptodate
```

Using `aptitude`:

```
aptitude versions vlc
```

Will output the complete list/tree of packages related to vlc and the installed ones including the *package vlc* will contain letter "`i`"(*meaning installed*) before package name.

Similar but a bit shortened:

```
aptitude search vlc -F "%c %p %d %V"
```

And more programming one:

```
dpkg -l vlc | grep -E "^ii" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Will output `2.2.1~trusty`

Comment: Aptitude, a great tool +1

Answer (score 3):

You can check version of an installed Ubuntu package by running

```
dpkg -l | grep <package_name>

dpkg -l | grep vlc
```

It will give you versions of vlc-related packages.

To get path to vlc binary run

```
which vlc
```

But in Ubuntu it is very rarely needed to know where the binaries are located, if they are installed using dpkg or apt.

Answer (score 2):

simply start this command

```
apt-cache policy vlc
```

*Sample output*

```
vlc:
  Installed: 2.2.0-1
  Candidate: 2.2.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

From `man apt-cache`

```
   policy [pkg...]
       policy is meant to help debug issues relating to the preferences file. With no arguments it will print out the priorities of each source. Otherwise it prints out detailed information about the priority selection of
       the named package.
```

---

And to check  the installed files:

```
dpkg -L grep vlc
```

*Sample output*

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/mime
/usr/lib/mime/packages
/usr/lib/mime/packages/vlc
/usr/lib/vlc
/usr/lib/vlc/libvlc_vdpau.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_splitter
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_splitter/libwall_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_splitter/libclone_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_splitter/libpanoramix_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libvaapi_drm_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libvaapi_x11_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libsdl_image_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/control
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/control/libxcb_hotkeys_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/visualization
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/visualization/libglspectrum_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/visualization/libvisual_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/vdpau
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/vdpau/libvdpau_deinterlace_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/vdpau/libvdpau_avcodec_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/vdpau/libvdpau_display_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/vdpau/libvdpau_chroma_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/vdpau/libvdpau_adjust_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/vdpau/libvdpau_sharpen_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/librdp_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/libpulsesrc_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/libvnc_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/libxcb_screen_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/services_discovery
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/services_discovery/libxcb_apps_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/services_discovery/libpulselist_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libgles2_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libaa_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_x11_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libglx_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_window_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libegl_x11_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_xv_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libgl_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libxcb_glx_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libcaca_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/video_output/libgles1_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libskins2_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/audio_output/libpulse_plugin.so
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/misc
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/misc/libxdg_screensaver_plugin.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop
/usr/share/kde4
/usr/share/kde4/apps
/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid
/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions
/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-opencda.desktop
/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-openbd.desktop
/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-openvcd.desktop
/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-opendvd.desktop
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/vlc
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/vlc
/usr/share/doc
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/svlc
/usr/bin/qvlc
/usr/lib/vlc/libvlc_vdpau.so
/usr/lib/vlc/libvlc_vdpau.so.0
/usr/share/man/man1/qvlc.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/svlc.1.gz
/usr/share/bug/vlc
/usr/share/doc/vlc
```

Comment: What does the policy keyword mean? Also does this mean the it is installed in /var/lib/dpkg/status?

Comment: oh and HOW do you upgrade this to 2.2 like you have ? I was about to start another thread asking how to update it. I can't update it using canonical, it says "Canonical does not provide updates for VLC media player. Some updates may be provided by the Ubuntu community"

Comment: @johnsmith to upgrade vlc check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/633987/how-to-install-vlc-2-2-1-in-ubuntu-15-04/633994#633994)

Answer (score 1):

open the terminal and type the following command

`type vlc` command also includes the word 'type'

This gives you from where it was called .

For vlc version do `vlc --version`

Comment: And how is it related to version?

Comment: It was a 2 part question really. So this still helps.

Comment: edited  @Pilot6 :)