# How may I can create or resize like c:drive or system drive partition in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

How may I can create/resize like  c:drive or system drive partition in ubuntu? where software are installed and Operating System is installed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `gparted` using the following command from a terminal(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

Once installed, start gparted. it will ask for authentication. Enter you password and you will be able to see and resize your HDD partitions.

**Exercise caution and take backups before doing these activities.**

Also note that you can't (and shouldn't try to forcefully) alter partitions with mounted file systems. It's also impossible to unmount file systems mounted at `/`, `/usr`, `/var` or similar, since they're crucial for the running operating system. Even `/home` is difficult in graphical mode. If you want to modify those, use the Live CD, DVD, or USB drive. The Ubuntu ISO comes with gparted tool in the Live session. So you don't even need to install it. Just open it and alter the size of the partitions.

Comment: how may i know where my softwares are installed and OS is?

Comment: Linux is fundamentally different from Windows. As in windows, you wont be encountering Drives(like C:/, D:/) Rather, everything in Linux is a folder or a file. We can mount any partition in a folder and one wont even realize that its a partition without going in depth. Coming to your question, the softwares in ubuntu are generally installed in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` or `/usr/share` folder. refer [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27213/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-windows-program-files-folder-where-do-things-g)

Comment: For more info, refer [this Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout)

Comment: Please note, that you can't (and shouldn't try to forcefully) alter partitions with mounted file systems. It's also hard to impossible to unmount file systems mounted at `/`, `/usr`, `/var` or similar, since they're crucial for the running operating system. Even `/home` is difficult in graphical mode. If you want to modify those, use a live system on a CD, DVD, or USB drive.

Comment: @DavidFoerster can i add your comment to my answer?

Comment: @astrob0t: Of course. Even if I didn't want you to, I'm not able to prevent it.

Comment: Thinking of it, your [first, lengthy comment](/questions/546054/how-may-i-can-create-or-resize-like-cdrive-or-system-drive-partition-in-ubuntu/546057#comment748142_546057) should be part of your answer too since it directly addresses a misconception of the question author.

Answer (score 0):

Press the "Super" key (windows key) and type GParted. Open the GParted Partition Editor.

In the GParted dropdown menu, you can select which device you want to partition, format, etc.

Comment: GParted will probably have to be installed first.