# Use HDD partition for data and SSD for programs

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, kubuntu, ssd, symbolic-link

first of all I need to say that I am completely a Linux noob. Today I decided to install Kubuntu and keep Windows for some programs I need for work.

So I have split my SSD and left 150 GB for Kubuntu and 200 GB from HDD. I have installed root on a 20 GB partition and left 130 GB for home. Now I want to use the 200 GB HDD for data (like on Windows C:/ for Windows, D:/ for data). Programs should be installed on SSD for better performance.

I have a few questions about this:

- Where does Kubuntu save programs installed with apt-get?
- How should I create the data drive (D:/ in Windows)? I have created a new ext3 partition with GParted. Is this the correct way? I can see the partition as a device in Dolphin (it contains a lost&found folder?), but I cannot create any files there...
- What is the smartest way to add the HDD partition for storing big files (Downloads, VirtualBox drives, ...)? Create a symlinks in `/home` to the HDD partition? If yes, how can I do this?

I am sorry for dump questions, I have never worked with Linux before :/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you already have a "D:" in Windows, Ubuntu can use that. There's no need to create another "data" partition (unless you want to). You could put `/home` in the HDD, a typical strategy, but then some programs (e.g. Steam games) may end up being installed there. No, ext3 in 2017 is NOT correct, use ext4, the default for Ubuntu, and the partitioon you created needs permissions adjusted. Again, for data sharing between OSes use NTFS.

Comment: In conclusion, nothing wrong with partitioning you've done in the SSD. OTOH, what you did in the HDD was unnecessary and impractical.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Michael. The thing is that I want to delete Windows completely in a few weeks. So I want to have everything perfect for Linux and nothing should be shared between them. I decided to leave /home on SSD for performance reasons, because there are also some program files. I just want to store bigger files on HDD like virtual machines or downloads to preserve the SSD.

Comment: You can still have the "data" partition as NTFS with only one caveat: Should it - the file system - need repair you'd have to use Windows or Windows tools. That said, and considering the new info, I assume you later intend to use both drives for Ubuntu. As such, you'll probably want to use the whole SSD for the OS. Having backups it's better to reinstall. Otherwise, because Windows was installed first, after deleting its partition/s, you'd need to move the Ubuntu partitions to the begging of the drive (then you can expand /home to use the now unallocated space after). ->

Comment: Managing partitions can result in data loss. The risk, albeit still low, is higher when moving partitions.

Comment: 1st question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27213/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-windows-program-files

Comment: 2nd question and 3rd question: Mostly unnecessary many of us consider `/home` to be the directory in which we store our data. I typically use the additional hard drive for this task and if I outgrow it I add another mounted at `/srv` SSD's I typically mount at `/` as I want my boot times and programs to be fast. Data is still more efficiently stored on a HDD (cost per gigabyte)