# What directory are applications installed into?

Tags: directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are my installed applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9024/where-are-my-installed-applications)

Just a Quick question

As i'm a newbie in Linux , im just curious that when you install any application through terminal or Software Center then ***in which folder the application is installed*** as we know that in window it is installed in Programs Folder but what about Ubuntu or any other distro ?